# activar/desactivar Switchery con variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Estoy usando: https://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/ para unos botones en este caso al registrar en el formulario estoy enviando el estado del boton por POST = off/on cuando retorna al momento de editar me marca el estado correspondiente del registro pero estoy haciendo una validación en donde no me esta tomando el atributo:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
  <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" id="seguro" name="seguro"/>
</div>
<script>
  var elem = document.querySelector('.js-switch');
    var init = new Switchery(elem, {
     color: '#0d6efd',
     secondaryColor: '#dfdfdf'
   });                               
 </script>
```

mi validación es la siguiente :

```
$('#seguro').val(data.seguro);
    if (data.seguro == 'on') {
      $('#seguro').attr('checked', true);
    }else{
      $('#seguro').attr('checked', false);
    }
```

con lo cual por lo que entiendo si tiene el atributo checked el input deberia de estar en estado activado pero no me esta tomando al momento de abir el modal.

Comment: Verifica qué valor tiene `data.seguro` en ese contexto.

Comment: si, ejecuto un alert e indica el valor que indica la base de datos si se registro activado es = on si se registro desactivado = off, de igual forma le añado el value ="" segun lo que indica la base de datos con el data.seguro

Comment: Y si pruebas así: `if (data.seguro.trim() == 'on') {` a veces se cuelan espacios o saltos de línea en el contenido y hay que limpiarlo con  `trim()`.

Comment: tambien lo probe asi y nada, sera por lo que veo al inspeccionar la pagina que me sale de esta forma : checked="checked" y me parece que solo deberia de ir checked, o es que esta bien como añado el atributo?

Comment: Cambia `attr` por `prop`, o sea: `$('#seguro').prop('checked', true);`  y `$('#seguro').prop('checked', false);` respectivamente.

Comment: cuando uso 'prop' sale : '<input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" id="seguro" name="seguro" data-switchery="true" value="on" style="display: none;">' cundo uso 'attr' : '<input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" id="seguro" name="seguro" data-switchery="true" value="on" checked="checked" style="display: none;">' parece que no toma el ´prop´ en este caso.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de jQuery estás usando?

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Es extraño, la versión de jQuery no es antigua, por lo que `prop` debería funcionar. No sé si haya alguna interferencia con respecto a Switchery. ¿No ves ningún error en la consola del navegador?

Comment: no me indica ningun error, y en el network cuando muestra el proceso me cargan los datos correctos, crees que sea por jerarquia de los script? ya que tengo el jQery arriba despyes el select2.min.js y por ultimo el public/js/paciente.js que es mi js

Comment: Si hubiera un problema de jerarquía te daría error en la consola.